# ASP.NET MVC disable button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `.cshtml` view that has a button and a text box that is a datepicker. How do I disable the button with `id = "submitButton"` if the textbox is null? Thanks

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="blah" disabled="@ViewBag.blah"
       class="btn btn-default" />
    &nbsp; &nbsp;       
    @Html.Label("my label:")
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    @Html.TextBox("Closed", "", new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in several different ways, easiest using javascript:

```js
$(".datepicker").change(function() {
  if ($(".datepicker").val())
    $("#submitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
  else 
    $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="blah" 
 class="btn btn-default" />
 <input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @RaziSyed! Great example as well.